# List of WMIEvent classes

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query, wql

Recently I have been learning about WMI and WQL. I found out the list of Win32 classes (from MSDN) that I can query for but I am not able to find out the list of event classes (should be the subset of the list of Win32 classes isn't it ?) Does any one have a list or some kind of cheat sheet for this? I am jsut asking this out of curiosity.

Example for an event class - **Win32_ProcessStartTrace**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to list WMI event classes in the `root\cimv2` namespace with C# and `System.Management`:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string query =
            @"Select * From Meta_Class Where __This Isa '__Event'";

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

        foreach (ManagementBaseObject cimv2Class in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cimv2Class.ClassPath.ClassName);
        }
    }
}
```

`root\cimv2` is the default WMI namespace so you don't have to use a `ManagementScope` instance. The WQL query passed to `ManagementObjectSearcher` is a WMI metadata query. It uses:

- `Meta_Class` to designate the query as a schema query, and
- `__This` property to recursively list `__Event` subclasses

(see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393278(VS.85).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719643(VS.71).aspx)).

WMI class is an event class if its provider implemented as an event WMI provider and must be a subclass of `__Event`. This doesn't mean that you can't use 'ordinary' WMI classes like `Win32_Process` and `Win32_Service` in WQL event queries. You just have to use one of the `__InstanceOperationEvent` derived helper classes like `__InstanceCreationEvent` or `__InstanceDeletionEvent`, and WMI will use its own event subsystem to deliver events.

Here is a sample WQL query that subscribes to `Win32_Process` creation events:

```
Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 5 Where TargetInstance Isa 'Win32_Process'
```

In this case you have to use the [`Within`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394527(VS.85).aspx) clause.

Answer (score 6):

[WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) is a great tool for learning WMI that, among other things, lets you explore WMI event classes on the local or remote computer and generate code for receiving event notifications.

**Edit:** Since you tagged your question as *C#*, you might be interested in the code for getting the list of event classes derived from a particular class programmatically:

```
using System.Management;
...

string ancestor = "WMIEvent";     // the ancestor class
string scope = "root\\wmi";       // the WMI namespace to search within

try
{
    EnumerationOptions options = new EnumerationOptions();
    options.ReturnImmediately = true;
    options.Rewindable = false;

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, "SELECT * FROM meta_class", options);

    foreach (ManagementClass cls in searcher.Get())
    {
        if (cls.Derivation.Contains(ancestor))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cls["__CLASS"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
catch (ManagementException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

Comment: This tool is very useful for poking around the available WMI classes.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't MSDN have a list of all the [MSMCA classes here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392706(VS.85).aspx)

**UPDATE:**
I don't do tons of work with WMI, but I just found this [WMI tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6430F853-1120-48DB-8CC5-F2ABDC3ED314&displaylang=en) that would have been helpful. It gives you a GUI for viewing the WMI hierarchy of objects, and even allows you to register and consume events. This should give you the information you need.

Comment: I saw that too, but the list doesn't seem to be what he wants. It doesn't even have the example class (Win32_ProcessStartTrace), unfortunately.

Comment: But (Win32_ProcessStartTrace) doesn't ultimately derive from WMIEvent. It has (__ExtrinsicEvent) as a parent class, but WMIEvent is a child of (__ExtrinsicEvent). The example he provides isn't a WMIEvent...