# How to list all WMI event classes using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

Using VBScript, how can I list all WMI classes that represent events?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, here's the same question, but asking for a C# solution: [List of WMIEvent classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043220/list-of-wmievent-classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WMI [schema query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393245%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for classes that inherit from [__EVENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394634%28VS.85%29.aspx). An example would be:

```
Function GetWmiEventClasses(computerName)
    Dim wmiRoot
    Dim eventClasses

    Set wmiRoot = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & computerName & "\root\cimv2")
    Set eventClasses = wmiRoot.ExecQuery("select * from meta_class where __this isa '__event'") 

    Set GetWmiEventClasses = eventClasses
End Function
```

**USAGE:**

```
Set eventClasses = GetWmiEventClasses("." )

If Not eventClasses Is Nothing Then
    Dim eventClass 

    For Each eventClass In eventClasses
        WScript.Echo eventClass.Path_.Class
    Next 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This will cause a credential error if remote systems are access proof. Use

strComputer = computerName

```
Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWMIService = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, "root\CIMV2", strUser, strPassword, "MS_409", "NTLMDomain:" + strDomain)

Set eventClasses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from meta_class where __this isa '__event'")

Set GetWmiEventClasses = eventClasses
```

Supply credentials as string and add to you code.

Then query the event class...

Dim eventClasses As Object
Dim EventClass As Object
Dim ServerName As String
Dim className As String

ServerName = ""

Set eventClasses = GetWmiEventClasses(ServerName)

```
If Not eventClasses Is Nothing Then
```

'        Dim eventClass

```
    For Each EventClass In eventClasses
        className = CStr(EventClass.Path_.Class)
        Call WriteToRTB_eventClass(className)
        WriteTextFile (className)
        
    Next
End If
```